# The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined when adding index

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I get this error when I try to add an index to a column. Any idea why and how I can address this.

This is how I add the index in my AppDbContext file.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasIndex(b => b.CategoryName).IsUnique();
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

This is the model I am trying to add to my index.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<unitItem> itemList { get; set; }
}
```

And I the error is being thrown here

```
            AppDbContext context = applicationBuilder.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                if (!context.Categories.Any())
            {
                context.Categories.AddRange(Categories.Select(c => c.Value));
            }
```

when I try to initialize my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the base class in your `OnModelCreating` method. `IdentityDbContext` uses `OnModelCreating` as well to configure its classes (like `IdentityUserLogin<string>`):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Call the base class first:
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.CategoryName).IsUnique();
}
```

Comment: Thank was going to spend another looking for this solution. Much appreciated.